# How to stop vim-surround removing newline?

Tags: vim, neovim, vim-plugin

With my cursor on the top curly brace, when I use `c-s-{-(` this piece of code:

```
test {
  hello world
  hello world
}
```

gets transformed into this:

```
test ( hello world
    hello world
    )
```

Whereas I would like it to respect the original whitespace, like so :

```
test (
    hello world
    hello world
)
```

How can I get vim-surround to behave like this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should try `cSB)` and give it a shot.

Otherwise when on nvim you should try https://github.com/kylechui/nvim-surround.

Comment: The plugin suggestion is irrelevant to the problem at hand.

Comment: The command works perfectly, thank you! I had no idea capital S was a thing.

I must ask, how did you find the command / where is it documented? 
I can't find it on [tpope/vim-surround's](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) github

Comment: `cS` is mentioned in the plugin's documentation.

Comment: @romainl it oddly makes a difference regarding this problem

Comment: Keep in mind that OP is asking about OG Surround, not that fork. `cS` is in OG Surround and solves their problem without having to use a different package so, if you think that fork is relevant, you should consider explaining why.

Comment: Because cS doesn’t fix it entirely. It still indents the whole block by +1 one space every time. Give it a try.